# How to read from variable by line

Tags: shell, sh

I need to read from a variable line by line, do some operations with every line and then work with the data afterwards. I have to work in sh.

I already tried this, but $VAR is empty since I assume, that I saved into it in a subshell

```
#!/bin/sh POSIXLY_CORRECT=yes
STRING="a\nb\nc\n" 
echo $STRING | while read line; do
*some operations with line* 
VAR=$(echo "$VAR$line") 
done 
echo $VAR
```

I also tried redirecting a variable...

```
done <<< $STRING
done < $(echo $STRING)
done < < $(echo $STRING)
```

...and so on, but only got `No such file` or `Redirection unexpected`

Please help.

Comment: `STRING` doesn't have multiple lines; `\n` is just pair of characters, not a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've guessed, variable assignments in a subshell aren't seen by the parent, and the commands in a pipelines are run in subshells.

Having to work in plain sh is a real buzzkill. All right, all right, here are a few ideas. One is to extend the life of the subshell and do your work after the loop ends:

```
string="a
b
c" 
echo "$string" | {
    var=
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        *some operations with line* 
        var=$var$line
    done 
    echo "$var"
}
```

Another is to use a heredoc (`<<`), since sh doesn't have herestrings (`<<<`).

```
var=
while IFS= read -r line; do
    *some operations with line* 
    var=$var$line
done <<STR
$var
STR
```

Other improvements:

- Escapes aren't interpreted in string literals, so if you want literal newlines put literal newlines, not `\n`.
- Make sure to empty out `$var` with `var=`. You don't want an environment variable leaking into your script.
- Quote variable expansions. Not needed in assignments, though.
- `$(echo foo)` is an anti-pattern: you can just write `foo`.
- It's best to keep variables lowercase. All uppercase is reserved for shell variables.
- Use `IFS=` and `-r` to keep `read` from stripping leading whitespace or interpreting backslashes.